# Why does Chrome not like overflow on input?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Chrome seems to not like having an overflow on certain input fields, it causes some very strange results. Use the following code to replicate. I don't understand why there is an offset.

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title> 
        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                overflow:           hidden; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" /> 
        <select><option>Hello</option></select> 
        <input type="submit" value="Ok..." />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you need hidden at first place?

Comment: take a look here at this discussion https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304210

Comment: Thanks Rex, just what I needed - @Mr.Alien - Think of any reason you want for using overflow: hidden, I was pointing out it was a very strange occurrence.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem any more on Chromium 32.0.1668.0 (228152), so I expect it to be fixed soon on the regular release.